# Android: Eclipse xml editor error can't display UI for layouts

Tags: android, adt

i have this error that won't display the Graphical Layout from my xml editor... this is the message and the stack trace 
Message on the Error Log on my Eclispe

```
activity_patient.xml: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.binding.FakeAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.BaseAdapter
```

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.binding.FakeAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.BaseAdapter
    at android.widget.FastScroller.getSectionsFromIndexer(FastScroller.java:512)
    at android.widget.FastScroller.getThumbPositionForListPosition(FastScroller.java:633)
    at android.widget.FastScroller.onScroll(FastScroller.java:458)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1323)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1707)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:449)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:333)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1638)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1389)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1163)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:674)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1730)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3554)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3179)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

I don't know how to fix this because when i ran my emulator.. my layout runs ok.. i just can't edit it easily i have to hard code it...
Any inputs would be helpful on how to fix this or does anyone of you have fixes on this issue my guess is that its on the adt plugin..

By the way im using Juno Eclipse and ADT latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known issue with custom layouts.

> The visual layout editor only loads classes that it reads from the
>   XML. Basically when  it finds a node in the XML that isn't a default
>   widget it asks eclipse to load the  corresponding class. It is
>   possible that the custom class loader we did doesn't  actually handle
>   the case where the loaded class requires loading another class from 
>   the project.

Here's a [similar problem](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6894)

here's a [solution](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/18424/), haven't tried it myself though..

Comment: hmm its better dat i wont try these things might cause some issues in my code.. my code is hard to trace its very very long hehe.. but thanks for the inputs though.. and i've found wat causes the error i think.. :D its because of my customadapter that manipulates the listview in that layout.. i tried getting the listview tag in my xml  and boom its works fine.. i can see the graphical layout again.. but if i put it back it displays the error again.. hehe i think i have to do this the hard way :D :D but thanks man!

Comment: yes, thats how i do it too. Replace the custom stuff with the default things to debug and switch it back when i'm done.

Answer (score 0):

You will also get the `ClassCastException` if you have multiple scrolling views on one screen.  For example, if you have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`,  you will see this exception.  Luckily, Eclipse underlines the problem and displays this:

> The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget (ListView)

when you hover over it.